# Assign variables to a MySQL iterative result set

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops

StackOverflow,

```
$resultpaid = $mysqli->query($paidquery);
while ($row=$resultpaid->fetch_array()) 
{
  print $row['paid'] .'<br />';
}
```

I realize this should be simple, unfortunately, I'm not well versed in PHP.  I'm trying to take the result set from this while loop and assign them to variables.  Basically right now it finds two rows, both with integer values.  So when it iterates through, it prints out 250 and 260.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to assign each row a variable in order to add the integers together, or reference them individually at a certain point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, try this,

```
 $total = 0;
 $resultpaid = $mysqli->query($paidquery);
 while ($row=$resultpaid->fetch_array()) 
 {
  $arr[] = $row['paid']; //gets individual values in an array
  $total += $row['paid']; //adds them up
  print $row['paid'] .'<br />';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to build an array with the datas.

```
$myArray = array();
$resultpaid = $mysqli->query($paidquery);
while ($row=$resultpaid->fetch_array()) 
{
    $myArray[$row['id']] = $row['paid'];
    print $row['paid'] .'<br />';
}
// $myArray here is filled up with your data
```